# Python. Параллельная отправка пакетов через сокеты

Tags: python, сокет, multiprocessing

Пытаюсь написать код, который будет одновременно отправлять в два порта компьютера разные пакеты.

Функцию, которая отсылает сами пакеты, я сознательно опустил. Интересует само распараллеливание процессов.

Для примера приведу два "icmp request" пакета - пинги до яндекса и гугла. Пинг до Яндекса должен уходить в интерфейс eth1, пинг до гугла должен уходить в eth2. Анализ отправки пакетов осуществляется с помощью Wireshark. Проблема в том, что 
1. пакеты отсылаются с обоих интерфейсов более, чем 10 раз.
2. пакеты отсылаются с НЕ равномерным интервалом.

Прошу помочь с кодом, который мог бы обеспечить отправку пакетов из обоих портов компа одновременно. Ниже привел кусок кода, которым я пытаюсь реализовать данную задачу.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

packet_1 = ping_YaRu
packet_2 = ping_GoogleRu

def fooPingInterface1():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print name, 'Starting 1'
    for i in range(10):
    packet_1.Send(eth1)
    time.sleep(2)
    print name, 'Exiting'

def fooPingInterface2():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print name, 'Starting 2'
    for i in range(10):
    packet_2.Send(eth2)
    time.sleep(2)
    print name, 'Exiting'


service1 = multiprocessing.Process(name = 'pingYandex', target = fooPingInterface1)
service2 = multiprocessing.Process(name = 'pingGoogle', target = fooPingInterface2)

interface_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = fooPingInterface1)
interface_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = fooPingInterface2)

interface_1.start()
interface_2.start()

service1.start()
service2.start()

service1.join()
service2.join()
```

vadim vaduxa, спасибо за ответ. Проблему параллельной отправки пакетов решил так:

```
def fooInterfaceSend1():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print name, 'Starting 1'
    for i in xrange(5):
    Packet1.Send_(eth1)
    time.sleep(2)
    print name, 'Exiting'

def fooInterfaceSend2():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print name, 'Starting 2'
    for i in xrange(5):
    Packet2.Send_(eth2)
    time.sleep(2)
    print name, 'Exiting'

service1 = multiprocessing.Process(name = 'Interface1', target = fooInterfaceSend1)        
service2 = multiprocessing.Process(name = 'Interface2', target = fooInterfaceSend2)

service1.start()
service2.start()

service1.join()
service2.join()
```

Функции fooPingInterface1() и fooPingInterface2() фактически дублируют друг друга. Поэтом для оптимизации кода, надо весь код завернуть в класс. Вместо двух функций fooPingInterface1() и fooPingInterface2() оставить одну приватную с возможностью принимать несколько переменных. Остался вопрос, как сохранить параллельность отправки пакетов при использовании приватной функции. Пока при использовании приватной функции пакеты уходят не параллельно, а последовательно, сначала 5 пакетов через первый, а потом 5 пакетов через второй интерфейс.

---

Ранее пакеты отсылались последовательно, а не параллельно, потому, что я делал вызов функции "target = fooInterfaceSend()", вместо присваивание target = fooInterfaceSend.

Помогает следующий код:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

packet_1 = ping_YaRu
packet_2 = ping_GoogleRu

def fooInterfaceSend(value, packet, interface, rest):
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print name, 'Starting 1'
    for i in xrange(value):
        packet.Send(interface)
        time.sleep(rest)
    print name, 'Exiting'

service1 = multiprocessing.Process(name = 'Interface1', target = fooInterfaceSend, args(10, packet_1, eth1, 2))        
service2 = multiprocessing.Process(name = 'Interface2', target = fooInterfaceSend, args(10, packet_2, eth2, 2))

service1.start()
service2.start()

service1.join()
service2.join()
```

Comment: а чем service отличается от interface ? таже самая функция

Comment: @jfs ицмп можно пулять с интерфейса особо не полагаясь на роутинг `ping -I eth1 77.88.8.8`

Comment: я к тому что роутинг можно не смотреть. но всетаки важно как инициализированна опущенная функция.. возможно питон гоняет объект меджу процессами

Answer (score -1):

Сам вопрос задал. Сам ответ нашел. Помогает следующий код:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

packet_1 = ping_YaRu
packet_2 = ping_GoogleRu

def fooInterfaceSend(value, packet, interface, rest):
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print name, 'Starting 1'
    for i in xrange(value):
        packet.Send(interface)
        time.sleep(rest)
    print name, 'Exiting'

service1 = multiprocessing.Process(name = 'Interface1', target = fooInterfaceSend, args(10, packet_1, eth1, 2))        
service2 = multiprocessing.Process(name = 'Interface2', target = fooInterfaceSend, args(10, packet_2, eth2, 2))

service1.start()
service2.start()

service1.join()
service2.join()
```

Прошу отметить, что здесь не приведена функция "Send" позволяющая отправлять пакет.